# Is it possible to summon a zombie with a custom sign in 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon a zombie holding a clickable sign that is guaranteed to drop, here's the command that'd give the sign to a player:

```
/give @p minecraft:sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickevent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"scoreboard players add @p money 10\"}},{\"text\":\"c\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"o\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"n\",\"color\":\"yellow\"},{\"text\":\"g\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"text\":\"r\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\"a\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\"},{\"text\":\"t\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"},{\"text\":\"z\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\"},{\"text\":\", \"},{\"text\":\"you won\",\"color\":\"gold\"}]",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Click Here\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tp @p -46 49 -46\"},\"italic\":true,\"underlined\":true,\"color\":\"blue\"}",Text3:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickevent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:air\"}},{\"text\":\"to recive \"},{\"text\":\"your\",\"bold\":true}]",Text4:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"p\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"r\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"i\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"text\":\"z\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\"e\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"}]"},display:{Name:"Place And Click"}}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Without the use of mods... The player has no way of clicking the sign.....

Comment: Alex that is incorrect. https://minecraftcommand.science/command-sign-generator is a website that will create a clickable sign with block entity tags

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use this command:

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~  {HandItems:[{id:sign,Count:1,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickevent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"scoreboard  players add @p money  10\"}},{\"text\":\"c\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"o\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"n\",\"color\":\"yellow\"},{\"text\":\"g\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"text\":\"r\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\"a\",\"color\":\"dark_purple\"},{\"text\":\"t\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"},{\"text\":\"z\",\"color\":\"dark_blue\"},{\"text\":\",  \"},{\"text\":\"you  won\",\"color\":\"gold\"}]",Text2:"{\"text\":\"Click  Here\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"tp @p  -46 49 -46\"},\"italic\":true,\"underlined\":true,\"color\":\"blue\"}",Text3:"[{\"text\":\"\",\"clickevent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"setblock  ~ ~ ~ minecraft:air\"}},{\"text\":\"to recive  \"},{\"text\":\"your\",\"bold\":true}]",Text4:"[\"\",{\"text\":\"p\",\"color\":\"red\"},{\"text\":\"r\",\"color\":\"gold\"},{\"text\":\"i\",\"color\":\"green\"},{\"text\":\"z\",\"color\":\"blue\"},{\"text\":\"e\",\"color\":\"light_purple\"}]"},display:{Name:"Place  And Click"}}},{}],HandDropChances:[2.0F,0.085F]}
```

It would spawn a Zombie one block above the command block, holding a sign in its main hand, with with the name "Place and Click", text with commands on it, and a 100% chance of dropping.